# How can you display all the combinations of elements in a list?

Tags: list, iteration, decomposition

```
art = list('ABBC')
combination = []

for i in range(3):
combination.append(art)
remove = art.pop(0)
art.append(remove)
```

Currently breaking down the problem and trying to do using .pop():
ABBC
ABCB
ACBB

However, when the loop continues and the variable art changes, it also changes the elements within the list too?

So i would want the output to be:

## ABBC

## ABCB

## ACBB

## BABC

## BACB

## BBAC

## BBCA

## BCAB

## BCBA

## CABB

## CBAB

## CBBA

## ABBC

And i would like to achieve this without a library?